# How to delete an edge in Orient DB by Gremlin query?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

Want to delete an edge between two vertices. For this I have tried something like this. It's not working.

```
g.traversal().V(reln.getStartNodeId()).bothE(oldRelationship)
.where(__.otherV().hasId(reln.getEndNodeId())).drop().iterate();
```

Comment: the syntax looks ok...is the problem that the edge is not dropping or are you getting an error? what result to you get if you remove `drop()` from that query?

Comment: I am not getting any error.But edge is not deleting from DB. I want to drop an edge from DB.

Comment: Same query is working for Neo4j but it's not working in OrientDB

Comment: what about my other question: what result to you get if you remove drop() from that query?

Comment: GraphTraversal<Vertex,Vertex>

Comment: well - i mean - iterate the traversal with `next()`....does it return the `Edge` that you want to delete? if not, then there is a problem in your data (or the parameters you are passing. if it does return the `Edge` to delete then it's a bug in the OrientDB implementation.

Comment: Before deleting I am checking edge is der or not using g.traversal().V(reln.getStartNodeId()).bothE(reln.getRelType()).where(__.otherV().hasId(reln.getEndNodeId())).hasNext() and this one is working fine only not able drop

Comment: i'd guess it is a bug in the OrientDB implementation then. perhaps the only other thing you might try to is to directly `g.E(edgeId).drop()` to see if it's a problem with the specific edge - that might be helpful information to those who try to figure out what the fix is to this problem.